# $resource POST request with payload in angular

Tags: angularjs, rest

I wanted to send a post request with a payload '{}' as required for the back end . I was using angular's $resource service and was not able to achieve this .  Googling I happened to see that 
`method(param,payload)` is the way to do that , but I could not make it work .

Below is my $resource factory

```
.factory('Dfs',['$resource',function($resource){
return $resource('http://'+server_ip+'/jax/search/',{},
 {
  query:{method:'POST'}
})}])
```

and in the controller I am calling

```
  .controller('DFl', function($scope,Dfs){

var d={};
 Dfs.query(d,function(resp)
 {
   console.log(resp);
 })  })
```

The payload I want to send is

```
{}
```

please help .

Answer (score 1):

I found one

```
    ResourceName.method(payload,function(a,b){
         //Handle the response here
    })
```

That did work ... Thank You all ..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send a simple POST request you can use the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#post) service.

```
var url = 'http://...';
var data = {};

$http.post(url, data).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result.data);
});
```

Here is a [simple demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7z2cRLQN2a66KRKUB7UR?p=preview).